# Let $V$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices, $B$ a fixed matrix, prove that $L_B:A\mapsto BA$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that $\operatorname{trace}(L_B) = n\times \operatorname{trace}(B)$ and $\det(L_B)= (\det(B))^n$. Moreover, I know that the matrix of $L_B$ in the standard basis is

\begin{pmatrix}
B_{11}&B_{12}&\cdots &B_{1n}\\
B_{21}&B_{22}&\cdots &B_{2n}\\
\cdots\\
B_{n1}&B_{n2}&\cdots &B_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}

where $B_{ij}$ is a diagonal matrix with as diagonal  value the element $b_{ij}$ of the matrix $B$.

> **Now, what about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B$ and $L_B$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that $L^k_B(A)=B^kA$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$ and deduce that for all polynomial $P$

$$P(L_B)(A)=P(B)A$$
and deduce the desired result.

Comment: Following your hint, one can conclude that they have the same minimal and characteristic polynomials. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: But, the degree of characteristic polynomial of $L_B$ is $n^2$ whereas the one for $B$ is $n$! So, they should not have the same characteristic polynomials!

Comment: Not the same characteristic polynomial but same eigenvalues with different multiplicities.

Comment: What about the minimal polynomials, are they exactly the same? I guess so following your hint.

Comment: Yes that's true.